# Darkened User Resizable Area C# WPF .NET-Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, user-controls

I'm trying to make a simple WPF application where you will be able to crop a video quickly and simply. I want it to look like and operate like how this website does it: https://clideo.com/crop-video

[image: Video crop example]

It darkens the video outside of the boundaries and has the rule of thirds guidelines. It can also be freely resized to any aspect ratio. Having the "grab" squares on the corners and sides would be nice but i am not too fussed about that :)

I've had a search already and came across this: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/let-user-move-resize-rectangle-wpf-c/

It operates great but if you look at the code it doesn't work very nicely and will be messy to implement the dark background I think, it is also from 2014 and there is probably a better way to do this in WPF nowadays. The only way I can think of doing the dark background is to have 4 dark rectangles on the top, right, bottom and left, resizing when you resize the crop area. There is most likely a better way to do this, hence why I am here.

In summary, I'm very new to WPF, not sure where to start, looking for some pointers :)

Comment: An alternative to four rectangles would be a Path with a CombinedGeometry with an inner and outer RectangleGeometry, and GeometryCombineMode set to Exclude.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens, your idea was helpful and led to me being able to create something with what I had, I think what I've got is pretty bad though and I need some tips on how to better utilise WPF's abilities so I can make cleaner code, what is a good way/place to upload my code so that it can be critiqued?